# Create circles dynamically in WPF the MVVM way

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am learning WPF and a newbie. I have this requirement. In the view model I have a timespan object. I would like to display the timespan as "one filled circle for each hour". What will be an optimal way to do this in WPF way. I tried the ItemsTemplate but couldnot find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [article about creating a Rating Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45210/WPF-A-Simple-Yet-Flexible-Rating-Control) It would be very similar.

The only MVVM thing about this might be how you gather the actual value that should be shown in the control. But building a control hasn't much to do with MVVM.

Let us know if you get stuck and try to ask specific questions.

Comment: Yes this was the last one in my mind, if I dont find anything. I am searching for a solution like collection+ItemsControl. My only problem is I dont have a collection but a single property here and have to generate a list of object. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Why are you looking for a collection/itemsControl if you only have a single property? You can easily generate/add as many circles as needed in the control. It's no collection.

Comment: from my prior UI dev experience I agree that the custom control solves the problem. Since I am a newbie I am just exploring WPF to find a way where this can be done declarative with data binding.

Comment: You will need to write a little code at least unless you are able to use/get a repeater kind of control

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create custom control that will generate to correct number of circles in code but if you prefer to mainly use XAML you have a few options.

If you want the circles to be generated inside a panel you can use an `ItemsControl` to perform the generation. The items generated are the circles so you need a view-model property with an element for each whole hour. These elements does not have any properties and can simply be of type `Object`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> Items { get; private set; }
```

You can update the number of objects in the collection:

```
Items.Clear();
var item = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < timeSpan.Hours; i += 1)
    Items.Add(item);
```

A simple view is then:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Ellipse Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="10"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want to layout the circles in a manner that is hard to do using a panel you can instead manually layout 24 circles in the XAML. You can then use a value converter to hide or show each circle based on a view-model property representing the hours:

```
// Remember to fire INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged when value changes.
public Int32 Hours { get; private set; }
```

The value converter will then convert the number into a visibility:

```
class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter {

  public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    var hours = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
    var visibleBelow = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
    // Alternatively use Visibility.Collapsed to completely remove the circle.
    return hours <= visibleBelow ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
  }

  public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

Each `Ellipse` will then bind the `Visibility` to the `Hours` property using a `ConverterParameter` that identifies the hour of the `Ellipse`:

```
<Ellipse
  Visibility="{Binding Hours, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}"/>
```

Comment: You can also use a custom Panel to arrange items within an ItemsControl. See ItemsControl.ItemsPanel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one you can do in raw XAML

- Databind an `ItemsControl` to a collection of booleans generated by
  your view models - one bool for each hour represented.
- Set `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to a template that includes an `Ellipse` with
  the same height and width and a border of [colour]
- Use [Actions / behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723952%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to set the Fill of the `Ellipse` to
  [colour] when the `DataContext` equals System.Boolean
  true

With this method, you will need to call raise PropertyChanged on the entire boolean collection each time one of them changes.